# deploying project to tomcat ROOT

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, deployment

I have deployed my project to `tomcat` root, and it works fine without any problem. To acheive this I created a ROOT file `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml` with content below:

```
<Context 
  docBase="/home/user/project.war" 
  path="" 
  reloadable="true"  />
```

So right now I can see my project under `localhost:8080/` without any problem.. but I don't know where my project has been extracted, there is even no `ROOT` directory under `TOMCAT_HOME/webapps`, any idea?

Comment: It's in `project.war`.

Comment: I mean where `project.war` is extracted?

Comment: AFAIK, unless you tell Tomcat to extract it, it doesn't do so. It can run your application fine from within the `war`.

Comment: but I want it to be extracted because I may apply some live changes for testing..

Comment: Yeah, play with that attribute.

Comment: @Nambari That is not correct. It only applies to WAR files in the HOst's appBase. See the definition of the unpackWARs attribute further up the page from the text you quoted.

Comment: @MarkThomas: Correct. Deleted my comment. unPackWar attribute documentation has this information defined explcitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Tomcat 8, it will unpack it into the Host's appBase.

Tomcat 7 will unpack it into the work directory but that is an internal Tomcat mechanism that I would not recommend interfering with. It is not intended as a location where you can deploy updates although it might work if you are lucky.